# Mixpanel alias on multiple devices

Tags: mixpanel

I'm confused by the way that Mixpanel alias() is supposed to work, despite the fact that Mixpanel have multiple pages attempting to explain it.

According to [this page](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-should-i-handle-my-user-identity-with-the-mixpanel-javascript-library), I should call alias() only once per user, because it will create a one-time mapping from their user ID to the device's generated ID. But shouldn't that mapping be the other way around? Let's say Bob starts my app on his phone and logs in, at which point I call alias() to map all his actions so far to his account. He then goes through the same process on his tablet - I would expect that I can then call alias() on that machine to do the same thing. But the page I mentioned specifically says not to do that, because it will map his user ID to that device's ID now.

I can call identify() on the multiple devices, but that does not link his previous events to his user ID.

I feel like I'm misunderstanding how this whole thing works, but I've now spent a few hours pondering this so I'm hoping it's confused someone else in the past too...

Answer (score 1):

I always understood `alias()` as mapping the identifiers both ways. I've had a similar case as you. I'm almost sure that it does not matter how many times you alias and in which direction you alias the identifiers.

This is not authoritative though, but rather based on past usage and possibly-flawed understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As they explain on their help documentation:
https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-should-i-handle-my-user-identity-with-the-mixpanel-javascript-library

> ## Ideal implementation
>
> The ideal integration that will allow you to track users from anonymous browsing all the way through signup and subsequent logins:
>
> 1. When a new user signs up, call (**once**)
>    mixpanel.alias("YOUR_USER_ID")
> 2. When a user logs in, call
>    mixpanel.identify("YOUR_USER_ID")

Applying this to your question, you need to use identify when the user do login with the mobile and another time when he do it with the tablet.

Comment: This seems to make sense, but on the page I linked it specifically says "Avoid calling mixpanel.alias() on a user more than one time" and then "If you’ve already mapped sally@gmail.com to Mixpanel distinct_id 12345, an attempt to then map sally@gmail.com to Mixpanel distinct_id 67890 will silently fail". Which rather suggests that calling alias() on whichever device is second isn't going to work. I'd agree that this logically makes sense, it just seems at odds with their docs.

Comment: Actually what I do is, when the app starts I check if there is a logged in user and if it exists I call identify with my ID for that user, else I call the alias function with my ID just after the registration process.

Comment: @AlbertPueyo So you confirm that if you use a second device with no cookie or session storage set yet, and you perform some anonymous tasks that triggers events in mixpanel, and then you log-in and identify, all those previous anonymous events will be linked and not lost? Common case for a guest checkout ecommerce that offers you log-in in the last steps only... Because the documentation doesn't explain how  on a second device anonymous events are linked to a user after logging in (assuming sign up, alias and all that stuff aready took place on another device, some time ago).